# How to disable notification based on its type?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

If type is equal to post, I do not want to show notification.
Notification object:

```
[aps: {
    alert = "some notification!";
    sound = default;
    title = "some title!";
    type = post;
    value = 6788;
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent from receiving the remote notification. The server should be in charge of not sending the notification in that case.